# Using pthread did not print expected value

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have created the following program:

```
void *thread(void *vargp) {
  int *ptr = (int*)vargp;
  printf("vargp = %p, *vargp = %d\n",vargp, *(int*)vargp);
  pthread_exit((void*)*ptr);
}

void *thread2(void *vargp) {
  int *ptr = (int*)vargp;
  *ptr = 0;
  pthread_exit((void*)31);
}

int main(){
  int i = 42;
  pthread_t tid, tid2;
  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread, (void*)&i);
  printf("i = %d, &i = %p\n", i, &i);
  pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, thread2, (void*)&i);
  pthread_join(tid, (void**)&i);
  pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
  printf("at the end i = %d\n",i);
}
```

I expect the last printf in the main function prints "at the end i = 42". However, it prints the following:

```
i = 42, &i = 0x7ffcf3b65c4c
vargp = 0x7ffcf3b65c4c, *vargp = 0
0
```

Since vargp is getting the same address as variable i, why *vargp did not print out value 42, but value 0?

Comment: Shouldn't \*vargp be \*ptr?

Comment: You are dereferencing a void pointer in the first thread. I'm not sure how this compiled.

Comment: you're setting the value to `0` in thread2...?

Comment: I.e. what's the problem??

Comment: Undefined behavior for accessing an object with a type other than its declared type and not through character type.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, i see your point. I realize the root cause like the answer said. Thank you.

Comment: @EOF, I did not fully understand. Could you elaborate more on the character type in your context?

Comment: @mnistic, you are right. I fixed the syntax.

Comment: You still have undefined behaviour because of the `pthread_join(tid, (void**)&i);`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, thumbs up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since vargp is getting the same address as variable i, why *vargp did not print out value 42, but value 0?

Your program exhibits a data race (a form of undefined behavior): its outcome depends on whether `thread` or `thread2` runs first, and that order is not guaranteed. On a multiprocessor machine (most common nowadays), both threads can run at the exact same time.

If you want to guarantee that `thread` will run before `thread2`, you need to *wait for it* (via `pthread_join`) *before* creating `thread2`.